# pass variable through hidden input php

Tags: php

I am anew to php please help...
I am trying to collect a variable (in specific the counter I used in my loop) on a $_POST after I submit my form.

```
<form action="reportingTemplate.php" method="post">
<?php
    function buildform() {
    if (file_exists('textt.txt')){

            $x = file_get_contents('textt.txt');
            $y = explode("\r\n", $x);

                $incr = 1;
            foreach ($y as $value) {
            $z = explode(",", $value);

            writehtml($incr,$z[1],$z[2],$z[0]);

      $incr++;
            }   
            if ($incr < 15)
                for ($incr = $incr; $incr<16; $incr++) {
                    writehtml($incr,"","","");

                }
        }
        else
        for ($increm = 1; $increm<16; $increm++) {
            writehtml($increm,"","","");
        }
    }
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" id="test" name"countt" value="<?php echo $incr; ?>"/> <!--error area -->
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

where I am getting my $_POST:

```
$the = $_POST["countt"];
echo $the;
```

Comment: You have not stated what is wrong?

Comment: apologies.   when I go to write the contents of the post nothing appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
$incr = 0;
function buildform() {
    global $incr;
    ...
    $incr++;
}
```

Declare `$incr` outside the function, then announce that it's a global variable you're manipulating from inside function `buildform()` then you can `echo` it...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `$incr` is outsite your scope.

Try this:

```
<?php
    $incr = buildform();
    function buildform() {
        // all your normal code here
        ...
        return $incr;
    }
?>
<input type="hidden" id="test" name"countt" value="<?php echo $incr; ?>"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I call the function buildform() elsewhere in the page, i just didnt include it in the code snippet

Comment: You misunderstood. I'm saying that you should place `$incr = 0;` before your function, so that it is in scope for both your function and external page code.

Comment: @poly: $incr would still need to be declared global inside the buildForm function. Just declaring it outside won't help, because the $incr inside the function has its own scope.

Comment: @MarcB - Ah, indeed. I guess he could return the value?

Comment: ah. understood.  thanks.  the only thing is that now I get a value of 0 on my post.  why isn't $incr now equal to the value after counting through the loop?

Comment: @mumis2012 - The function has its own scope, which means that the `$incr` in it isn't the same as the `$incr` outside it. I'll update with a way to fix this.

Comment: @mumis: because PHP's variable scope is function-level. If you have $incr outside and a $incr inside, they're two completely separate independent variables. UNLESS you do `global $incr` inside the function, in which case PHP knows you want to use the $incr that's defined outside the function: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a typing error in your file:

replace:
    `name"countt"`

with:
    `name="countt"`

EDIT:
On another note, realize that HTMLforms, even hidden values, can be easily edited by anyone visiting the page, so passing the value trough a form might not be the best option. You might want to look at [$_SESSION](http://de.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) .

Comment: thanks. after I fixed that error nothing still gets written on echo

Comment: Okay. Tell us what output you get when you use `var_dump($_POST)`. This might help in finding the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't called `buildform()` anywhere, so all you're doing is outputting `<form>` with one hidden (empty) input and a submit button.

Comment: I am calling buildform(), I just did not include it in the snippet i pasted above